# suppress g++ warning cast from type 'A' to type 'B' casts away constness

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings

I am using g++ and I am compiling a linux c++ project. I get

```
src/fileC.cpp:181618: warning: cast from type 'const t__DeviceID*' to type 't__DeviceID*' casts away constness
```

Is there any -W option that suppresses that warning?

In normal cases we resolve that warnings, following the suggestion of the compiler, but for this file - which is not our code - we don't want to modify it, at least for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `-Wno-cast-qual` is probably what you want, you also might want to add in general the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` option to gcc, which will show you for almost all diagnostics which parameter caused it.